# EntityDataSource concatenate two fields

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have EDSC and I try to concatenate two columns in a select statement. I try something like this:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="srcData" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=edm"
DefaultContainerName="edm" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="Staff"
Select="it.[StaffID], NewName = it.[Staff_Name] + it.[Staff_Surname]" Where="it.Retired=False">
```

Is there any way to do something like this: NewName = it.[Staff_Name] + it.[Staff_Surname]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with `AS` in the `Select` property of the EntityDataSource:

```
Select="it.StaffID, it.Staff_Name + it.Staff_Surname AS NewName"
```

Comment: What if the field datatype is not a 'string' but instead an int ?